# wso2 create new user and assign role with REST APIs

Tags: rest, wso2

I'm currently using wso2 v3.2.0 and I'm trying to create a new user and assign them a role created from carbon admin panel, using their RESTful APIs.

To create the user I'm currently using the `/v1.0/me` endpoint from Identity Server, and the payload is just the one given in the example from the documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#mePost)

The user is correctly added and I can interact with it from the carbon admin panel.

Now I'd like to assign this user some roles, like `Internal/creator` and `Internal/subscriber`.
How can I achieve this?
I can't seem to find any endpoint for this requirement in the identity server documentation.
I've tried adding to the request body the `role` field but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCIM endpoints to create a user and assign roles.

1. Create User - POST request to `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Users` endpoint

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser

2. Assign the role to user - PATCH request to `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Groups/{group-id}` endpoint

- If you want to assign `Internal/creator` role to the user, get the group id of that role by GET `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Groups?filter=displayName+eq+Internal/creator`
- send a PATCH request to `https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Groups/{group-id}` endpoint (replace the {group-id})
- In payload, you need to specify the username and id of the user that you want to assign

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Groups%20Endpoint/patchGroup

Comment: Hi thank you very much :) I'm trying with the scim2/Users endpoint. I tried creating an access_token with `https://<ip>/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin` to authenticate my POST request but I get a `403 - Forbidden` response if i try to create a user. How can i solve this? The documentation says that it requires `/permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/view` but I don't know where to grant them. Thanks

Comment: When you are sending the token request, pass the required scopes. as a query param . eg: `https://<ip>/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=internal_user_mgt_create` (internal_user_mgt_create is the required scope for user creation). Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/scope-based-authorization-for-internal-rest-apis/#scope-based-authorization-for-internal-rest-apis

Comment: It seems required scope is not included in IS 5.10.0 docs. refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser to find the required scope for each operation

Comment: Ok it looks like adding the `scope` you suggested me changes something. But now I get a `200` response with a whole webpage asking me to login to wso2 as body response, instead of the `201` response shown in the documentation. I'm using postman as the client.

Comment: Ok I'm creating a token like this `https://<ip>:8243/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=internal_user_mgt_create`, and it gives me back a token with scopes `default internal_user_mgt_create`, then I use the token to authenticate my request to `https://<ip>:9443/scim2/Users` but it gives me `403 forbidden`

Comment: Also tried the `https://<ip>:9443/oauth2/token` endpoint but same result